# How to refer or access the custom made permissions in `has_perm()` and `required_permissions`, in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-permissions

I want to know that how do I refer the custom made permissions in the `has_perm()` method of `User` Model and `required_permissions` attribute of `PermissionRequiredMixin` Class?

Let's say I create the following custom permission:

```
content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(User)

Permission.objects.create(
                codename='custom_permission',
                name='Custom Permission',
                content_type=content_type,
            )
```

and suppose my django app where I created this custom permission is named as:

```
mycustomapp
```

How will I refer/access this custom permission in `has_perm()` method and `required_permissions` attribute?

I tried following for `has_perm()`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

user = User.objects.all()[0]
user.user_permissions.add(Permission.objects.get(name="Custom Permission"))
user.save()

user.has_perm("mycustomapp.user.custom_permission")
```

But it resulted in False, instead of True, even though running `user.user_permissions.all()` show the newly added permission

and I tried this for `required_permissions` attribute:

```
class CustomView(PermissionRequiredMixin, View):
    required_permission = ["mycustomapp.user_custom_permission"]
```

But it does not work and when I go to this View on front-end I get `Forbidden 403` error, even though the logged in user has this required permission.

Can anyone tell me how do I refer the custom made permission in `has_perm()` and in `required_permissions`. Please tell me while considering all the details exactly as I gave above in example.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved it myself, by doing bit of search and debugging. So, basically `has_perm()` method and `required_permissions` attribute, follow the following syntax for permission to access/refer it:

```
[django-app-name].[permission-code-name]
```

Replace `[app-name]` with the name of your django app and replace `[permission-code-name] with the code name of permission you want to refer or access. Look at the [docs for Custom Permissions here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions) and [examples of permissions being accessed/referred here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#permission-caching)

You can get the code name of any permission by following:

```
p1 = Permission.objects.all()[0]  # Getting a random permission for this example

p1_code_name = p1.codename  # Getting the code name of the permission
```

So, I solved my issue by accessing/referring the permission in `has_perm()` method in following way:

```
user = User.objects.all()[0]

user.user_permissions.add(Permission.objects.get(name="Custom Permission"))
user.save()

user.has_perm("mycustomapp.custom_permission")
```

and in `required_permissions` attribute, in following way:

```
class CustomView(PermissionRequiredMixin, View):
    required_permission = ["mycustomapp.custom_permission"]
```

Comment: It does not work at all for me. This is so strange. The permission is assigned to the user, but `has_perm` is not working and always returns False

Comment: Update: it does work ... but not right when I do `user.user_permissions.add`. There seems to be some kind of delay. When following the code with pbd, if I assign the permission at one line, and I test the permission at the following line ... It does not work and `has_perm` returns False... but the permission shows up in `user.user_permissions.all()`